# "Around" and/or "About"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I know it is right to state:

> Is the teacher *around* ?

But is it equally right to state:

> Is the teacher *about* ?

I have heard native English speakers say the latter, but is it correct?

Comment: Check this post at _ELL_: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26666/about-vs-around

Comment: Thanks @Eilia, so it is a British thing?

Comment: As pointed out in the mentioned post, *about* is more common in UK.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary meaning of ***about*** as a [preposition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/about#Preposition) :

> 1. In a circle around; all round; on every side of; on the outside of.
> 2. **Near**; **not far from**; regarding approximately time, size, quantity.

Wiktionary meaning of ***about*** as an [adverb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/about#Adverb) :

> 1.**Not distant**; approximate.
>
> - On all sides; around.
> - Here and there; **around**; in one place and another; up and down.
> - Nearly; approximately; with close correspondence, in quality, manner, degree, quantity, or time; almost.
> - **Near**; in the vicinity.

Comment: Thanks @Yohann V. for the definitions, but I am not quite sure you addressed the question.

Comment: @SolaOderinde I edited to underline the close meanings of around